# Reverse-exchange file names of files in a folder from bottom up

Tags: scripting, rename, mv, for

I have a some jpg files in a certain folder:

```
hg_test_spr.jpg
hg_test00001.jpg
hg_test00002.jpg
hg_test00003.jpg
hg_test00004.jpg
hg_test00005.jpg
hg_test00006.jpg
.
.
.
hg_test01200.jpg
```

I want to rename the files in reverse order, so that the name of the first file will be exchange with the last file, second one with the second last and so on.

In other words:

```
hg_test_spr.jpg --> DO NOT RENAME THIS
hg_test00001.jpg --> hg_test01200.jpg
hg_test00002.jpg --> hg_test01199.jpg
hg_test00003.jpg --> hg_test01198.jpg
hg_test00004.jpg --> hg_test01197.jpg
hg_test00005.jpg --> hg_test01196.jpg
hg_test00006.jpg --> hg_test01195.jpg
.
.
.
hg_test01199.jpg --> hg_test00002.jpg
hg_test01200.jpg --> hg_test00001.jpg
```

I can get the list of files in reverse order in this way:

```
ls *.bmp | tac | tee reverse_order.txt
```

Or perhaps better would be:

```
ls *hg_test0*.bmp | tac | tee reverse_order.txt
```

And then maybe something like this:

```
mkdir renamed
for file in *hg_test0*.bmp; do read line;  cp -v "${file}" "renamed/${line}";  done < reverse_order.txt
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are files upto 1000 have four numerical digits and from higher have five?

Comment: If that is the case lexicographically, `hg_test001000` would come after `hg_test0010` which would be incorrect

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in my post. My original files all have the same number of digits. I will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `hg_*[0-9].jpg` expands to all the files that you'd like to rename, in the correct "forward" order, and that you'd like to write the renamed files into the subdirectory `renamed`.

Using `bash`:

```
mkdir renamed || exit 1    # fail if this directory exists
names=( hg_*[0-9].jpg )

for (( i=0; i < "${#names[@]}"; ++i )); do
    cp "${names[i]}" renamed/"${names[-(i+1)]}"
done
```

This first generates a list of filenames that are kept in the `names` array.
The loop goes through this generated list of names and picks a new name for each file at an offset from the end of the list.  No existing file will be modified and copies with new names will be written to the `renamed` folder.

Comment: Why so complicated? This does exactly what the sample code in my original post does, but the code is unnecessarily complicated and long.

Comment: @benett If your code does what you want it to do, then I don't quite see the point of your question. My code just uses an array instead of a temporary file. It also supports any weird filename that you may want to throw at it (including names with embedded newlines, even if your files may not be that strange).

Answer (score 1):

Going by your numerical ordering of files with 5 digits representing it, you could just use the glob features of the shell to rename as you would want to

```
shopt -s nullglob
fileList=(hg_test[0-9]*)
count="${#fileList[@]}"

for file in hg_test[0-9]*; do 
     echo "$file" "hg_test$(printf "%05d" "$count").jpg"
     ((count--))
done
```

This will basically `echo` the actual file name with the replaced file name. Once you find the names are intact as expected, remove the `echo` and use the `mv` command.